# how to get all the values in table to chart values in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

am using the following code. am getting only the first value and it has been displaying in table. how to get all the values and display in chart. though am using for loop am getting only one value. can someone give some suggestion how to proceed thanks.

```
var chart;

var chartData = <?php
        for($i=0;$i<count($six_year);$i++) {

         ?>[{
    year: "<?php echo $six_year[$i]['year']; ?>",
    visits: <?php echo $six_year[$i]['total']; ?>
    }
    ];
<?php

 }
             ?>
```

Comment: It's because your code in the end looks like [{"year":"2000","visits":15"}][{"year":"2001","visits":38"}]. The [ brackets must be outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $chartData=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($six_year);$i++) {
        $chartData[]=array('year'=>$six_year[$i]['year'],'visits'=>(int)$six_year[$i]['total']);
    }
    $chartData=json_encode($chartData);
?>
<script>
    var chart;
    var chartData ='<?php echo $chartData;?>';
</script>
```

Comment: [{"year":"0","visits":"200003677"},{"year":"2012","visits":"30"},{"year":"2013","visits":"60"}] am getting this format but need it as [{"year":"0","visits":200003677},{"year":2012,"visits":30},{"year":2013,"visits":60}]

Comment: And what is the `difference` in between both, other than the `quotes` on `integer value`

Comment: that chartData has been taking the values as the below only so

Comment: Try `'visits'=>(int)$six_year[$i]['total']` or see above answer I've made changes in it.